# Small padding between Tablayout and Viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm trying to find out how to delete this white padding line:[image]

my `activity`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".activity.ShowUI">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/show_ui_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/show_ui_tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/black"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabMode="fixed">
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/show_ui_viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

I can't find where the problem is. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Remove The `android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"` from the TabLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".activity.ShowUI">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/show_ui_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/show_ui_tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/black"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabMode="fixed">
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/show_ui_viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Or alternatively, you can set the height of TabLayout to ?actionBarSize instead of specifying it as minHeight like this

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context=".activity.ShowUI">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/show_ui_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/show_ui_tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/black"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabMode="fixed">
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/show_ui_viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>
```